# Is there a way I can perform one PHP function first and then execute another function after the first function?

Tags: php

Is there a way I can perform one PHP function first and then execute another function after the first function?

Comment: Umm, could you clarify?  Because as phrased, that's how it always works. `someFunction(); someOtherFunction();` they execute sequentially.

Comment: This is a real question...admittedly unusual, but not hard to understand

Comment: IMO, a better question would be "is it even possible to execute functions out of sequential order?" or "Can a function be made to execute while another function is still busy".

Comment: It's an almost zen like experience... like the question 'Is?', to which I can only reply "yes", but that tends to spark philosophical debates.

Comment: This was pretty disheartening. A slightly confusing but ultimately clear question got downvoted, fairly poorly answered, and ultimately closed, all because the question seemed too basic for everyone

Comment: @bob That's a better question if you know that the standard PHP behavior is sequential execution; I'm guessing this person doesn't know that

Comment: @Michael Mrozek: This could only possibly elicit a "read the manual" answer.  I'm interested to know, which languages do _not_ require sequential execution of functions, if that's even possible.

Comment: @bob It's certainly possible; Prolog is a good example I think. And this is completely not trolling

Answer (score 6):

PHP executes code sequentially. If you have two function calls:

```
foo();
bar();
// more code
```

it will execute the lines in `foo` sequentially, return to the line after that call (`bar();`), and execute it, which will call `bar` and execute its lines sequentially. Then `bar` will return to the line after the `bar();` call (`// more code`) and execution will continue there

Answer (score 4):

```
if (function1()) (
    function2();
)
```

?

Comment: If you want function1 to return a boolean and only call function2 if function1 returns true, then this is what you want.

Answer (score 2):

```
func1();
func2();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could always nest the function calls, so that the last step in function 1 is executing function 2. This is assuming, of course, that the execution of Function 2 ALWAYS follows Function 1.

That is,
    `function1()
    {
        // do stuff;
        function2();
    }`

Comment: Why that?... it is the same as executing them separately one after another... as `function(); someOtherFunction();`

Comment: Good question. It's simply a matter of, if this is always the case, it saves writing by 50%.